# Heatmap in Google Maps SDK for iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

Is there a way to add a heatmap layer with the  [Google Maps SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/)?

Note: I am refering to the same feature that exists in the [Javascript version of Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap).

Comment: What do you mean by "the heatmap function"? Are you referring to something [like this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap)?

Comment: Yes... I am trying to do exactly that - but that doesn't seem to be supported in the SDK for iOS.

Comment: @rufo google has provided support for iOS to. check my answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Heatmaps don't appear to be supported by the iOS SDK. However, you could try something like [LFHeatMap](https://github.com/gpolak/LFHeatMap) which allows you to generate a heatmap as a `UIImage` given a set of data points. You should then be able to add this as a [tile layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/tiles) to your map.

Comment: Hi Michael Mior. I have used the same for showing HeatMap.When i m scrolling zooming Map the image(heat map layer) is also moving. I want to know is there any way to let it be stable on those lat long only?

Comment: @Niharika This should be asked as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Google had updated their libraries, now they are providing support for iOS too. Developers looking to integrate heat map make use of it.

1. Please refer [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/utility/heatmap) link for further detail about heat map.
2. Also check out the sample project provided by google on [Github](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-ios-utils).
3. Install heat map by using following comand `pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'`

Thanks.