# Heat map with Google map iOS SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, heatmap

I want to add my project Heat map using GoogleMap on iOS. I found the heat map not supports google map for iOS. And i also found one demo but is in Apple(native) map.
So any one know how to add heat map using google map. Please help me.

Comment: Did you check this https://github.com/gpolak/LFHeatMap?

Comment: @Kamlesh Shingarakhiya Check this-: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296872/heatmap-in-google-maps-sdk-for-ios

Comment: @RajeshkumarR Yes i did and it is also in native map not google map btw thanks

Comment: @TusharSharma thanks but not helpful

Comment: Hey did you find the solution?

Comment: @Niharika It is not possible to set Heat map with Google map so i changed and using Apple(native) map.

Comment: @KamleshShingarakhiya I have used the same for showing HeatMap. But When i m scrolling or zooming Map the image(heat map layer) is also moving. I want to know is there any way to let it be stable on those lat long only?